# How can i to deploy my PWA on remote server?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, deployment, progressive-web-apps

I developed a Progressive Web App (PHP and JavaScript based) and i upload it on remote server LEMP (Debian/Nginx based) through FileZilla.
How can i deploy in future the updates without to use FTP?
What tools exists for to manager the next versions of my web app?

If it is of utility i use VSCode for coding.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can't update your web app without FTP. In order to update a new service worker, it needs to have at least one byte different than the previous version.

And the only way to update the service worker file is via FTP.

If you can't use FileZilla for whatever reason, you can try alternatives like editing files through Cpanel File Editor.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use free hosting like Github Pages, Netlify or Firebase. And automate the deployment of your front each time you commit something on a git repository. 
This solution only works for your static files. not for your backend using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your replies.

I found the right solution for me following this article: https://amifactory.team/blog/how-to-deploy-a-website/#simplewayscprsyncftp

In pratice i use ***lftp*** utility to sync my local website with my website on remote server.

The good notice is that "lftp" copy changed files only, reducing the uploading time and copying / overwriting the new files only at the end of the "lftp" process.